# Referencing a sibling changeset in a rollback section

Tags: liquibase

I'm having an issue trying to rollback a changeSet by referring sibling-changeset.

master-changelog.xml

- includes v.1.changes.xml (here is the table created)
- includes v.2.changes xml (here the table dropped and I would like to refer a changeset from v.1.changes.xml as a rollback)

However no matter how do I reference the changeset in v.1.changes.xml it's not visible to v.2.changes.xml and I'm getting liquibase.exception.SetupException: liquibase.parser.core.ParsedNodeException: Change set not found.

master-changelog.xml

```
<include file="v1/v1.changes.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
<include file="v2/v2.changes.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
```

v1.changes.xml

```
  <changeSet id="1" author="dima">
    <createTable tableName="test-table">
      <column name="test" type="number"></column>
    </createTable>
  </changeSet>
```

v2.changes.xml

```
  <changeSet id="1" author="dima">
    <dropTable tableName="test"/>
    <rollback changeSetAuthor="dima" changeSetId="1" changeSetPath="src/main/resources/std/v1/v1.changes.xml"/>
  </changeSet>
```

Comment: I think that is not how it is supposed to work. You create a changeset 1 and create a table in it. If something is not right, you can run the same changeset with `rollback` command to undo things. If you have another changeset (file number 2) you have another change. You can of course drop the table in the second changeset and therefore kind of undo stuff from the first file but this is not a rollback of the first file. It is a new change.

Comment: But I don't want to undo the 1st change, I just want to undo the 2nd change thus getting the same table state as it would be fresh after applying the 1st change.

Comment: I just skimmed over the rollback doc - I didn't even know that it is possible to back-reference on "old" changeset on rollback - sorry for the misleading info. You could check your `databasechangelog` table (column `filename`) for the file `v1.changes.xml`. Does it really have the value `src/main/resources/std/v1/v1.changes.xml`. I think liquibase compares `id, author, path` to find the original changeset. Maybe the path is not correct?

Comment: just doublechecked the `databasechangelog` table, it really contains the paths starting from `src/main/resources`

Comment: Hard to tell when I can't reproduce it. My best guess would still be that it has to do with the `path`...

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're using Maven, so this answer will be Maven specific, as I have not been able to reproduce the solution on the command line.

First of all, it's possible that Liquibase is confused because you're using the same changeSet id in both files, and I'm not sure if it correctly scopes those ids to the changeSet file, or if the ids need to be global. You might first try changing the id on the second changeSet and see if it clears it up for you.

If that's not the issue, then the trick to getting this to work is to make sure your relative references are all in the context of the Java classpath. As I interpret your example, the classpath resources of your files would be:

```
std/master-changelog.xml
std/v1/v1.changes.xml
std/v2/v2.changes.xml
```

When running your migration, your `changeLogFile` setting should reference the classpath resource, not the disk file; i.e. `std/master-changelog.xml` instead of `src/main/resources/std/master-changelog.xml`. This puts the origin changelog in a classpath context rather than a file context.

In your `v2.changes.xml`, you then refer to the first change using the classpath resource name: `v1/v1.changes.xml`. This should allow Liquibase to find it correctly.

If you have more than one level of changeLog file inclusion, you might be running into [this issue](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/pull/595) which prevents Liquibase from finding sibling changeLogs below the first level of inclusion. Until the pull request is merged and released, you'll be limited to a single level of file inclusion.

This solution is assuming you're using the Maven plugin, liquibase will still find the changelog, since Maven puts your resource files on the classpath by default. I also attach the plugin to the `process-resources` step (or later) so that the source resources will be in the `target/classes` directory when the migration is run.